# sphinx: filtering by id doesn't affect the speed of a query using quorum

Tags: sphinx

I have an rt-index(posts) containing 15 thousand records. I am running the following
query on this index:

```
select id from posts where match('"word1 word2 word3 word4 word5"/3');
```

After that I launched the same query but for a small number of records. Like this

```
select id from posts where id > 14900 and match('"word1 word2 word3 word4 word5"/3');
```

According to my logic, this query should search this words only in 100 records and the
query execution time should be less. But it is not. Query execution time has not changed.
Then I deleted the first 14,900 records from the index and run again the second query.
This time, the query execution time has decreased significantly.

Does this mean that the quroum query first searches for all matches in the whole index
and then filters the result by id? If so, how can I increase the speed of the query for
the second case?

Answer (score 1):

The fulltext match runs first. The attribute filters are applied on the result of the fulltext match. There is however an early rejection testing for attribute values - if they are out of the range, the query execution is stopped (for example if you do `gid<10` but index doesn't have values for `gid` in that range the query will finish fast with zero results returned).